# Bootstrap cuts the link as btn to half on hoover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="brand" href="admin">My Page</a>
                    <div class="nav">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><?php echo anchor('admin', 'Home') ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/emails', 'Eails') ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/banners', 'Banners') ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/text', 'Text') ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/meta', 'Meta') ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/pass', 'Password') ?></li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/logout"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i>Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div><!--/.container -->
            </div><!--/.navbar-inner -->
        </div><!--/.navbar -->
```

And the result is OK, however on hover it creates something like this:

[image]

And there is an animation when it scrools up/cuts to the half of the button.

Any idea how to "turn off" the scrolling up effect on hover in bootstrap?

Comment: Please can you share the css where `icon-off icon-white` is located

Comment: I don't have redeclard them at all.

Comment: If I remove the <i> part the animation still remains ;( I guess it has nothing to do with <i class="icon-off icon-white"></i>

Comment: Can you post the css?

Comment: I haven't redecared nothing in bootstrap except the color of the button. It shrinkds from the bottom in half maybe 50% for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: It seems like only the background is travelling up? Why is that? the border of the button stays ok?

Comment: You need to post the CSS before anyone is gong to help you.

Comment: @Derfder Can you please read the answer posted here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950072/bootstrap-dropdown-button-turns-half-black-on-clicking/14950463#14950463

Comment: wow, thanks. please post it as an answer so I can tick your answer as the winning one, tahnks.